# Alice, Bob and his 1956-Triumph

Tags: combinatorics

> Alice challenges Bob with a puzzle and Bob accepts it even before Alice told him specifically what it is about :)
>
> He must secretly write down a list (list A) of 20 positive rational numbers, not necessarily different from each other and put the list in a sealed envelope. Then Bob must give Alice a list (list B) of different numbers, each of which can be either one of the numbers in his list A, or the sum of more than one numbers in list A. Then Alice must try to find the numbers of list A. If she manages to find 2 or more sets of 20 numbers (from the numbers of list B), by which she can guess the numbers of list A, then Bob must donate her his priceless 1956 Triumph TR3. If, however, by the numbers in list B there is only one way to guess the 20 numbers in list A, then Bob will pay Alice one dollar for each of the numbers in list B. What is the minimum number that Bob must pay to Alice (to save his Triumph)?

This was given to me as a challenge from a friend. I am obsessed with maths and combinatorics but, alas, with this one I can't even think of where to start from! (and I'm not even sure what category to assign it to!! I chose "combinatorics" only by intuition!!)

Comment: If Bob doesn't accept the challenge, he doesn't have to pay anything. :-)

Comment: @HansLundmark: good point, I will rephrase it!

Comment: I don't understand. What is so special about this problem to have so many upvotes?

Comment: @Aqua That happens frequently lately, I don't understand it either.

Comment: Haha maybe the 1956 TR3 Triumph :) At least this is what hit my attention :))

Comment: And that is the reason you upvote? @TomGalle

Comment: No, I said that this is what hit my attention (in reading the question). I upvoted because I am really interested in reading some solutions and also try it myself.

Comment: As phrased, I think that Bob should give her an empty list for list B. She can't find any way to guess the numbers in list A, so she gets neither the motorcycle nor the money. But since this is obviously not the intended solution, the question clearly needs more work.

Comment: It probably should be "if there are at least two different lists $A_1$ and $A_2$ from which we can create list $B$, Alice gets motorcycle". Is it correct? Also, can we use one number from $A$ several times in the same sum? For example, if $A = \{1, 10, 100\}$ (using $3$ numbers instead of $20$), can Bob write $3$ in $B$?

Comment: To be pedantic, a Triumph TR3 is a car, not a motorcycle.  Also, the web seems to think that you can get a flawless one for \$46K, so that definitely puts spending \$$2^{20}$ to avoid losing it in perspective.

Comment: Well for starters, $|B|\le20$ clearly won't work. If $B$ is nonempty and elements of $B$ are distinct sums of distinct elements from $A$ (summing at least one element), is $|B|=21$ dollars enough? $A=\{1,10,10^2,\dots,10^{19}\}$ and $B=A\cup\{S(A)\}$ where $S(A)$ is the sum of all elements from $A$, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

(it's essentially solution from @Vepir's comment, slightly modified to make proof simpler)

If $x \in B$, then some number from $[\frac{x}{20}, x]$ is in $A$ (we can't get $x$ by using numbers greater than $x$, or by using at most $20$ numbers smaller then $\frac{x}{20}$). So the idea is to use $20$ numbers from $B$ to make $20$ non-overlapping intervals for elements of $x$ (thus ensuring that each interval contains exactly one element from $A$), and then adding one more element to ensure all the numbers are from right border of corresponding intervals.

To do it, let $A = \{1, 10^2, 10^4, \ldots, 10^{38})$ and $B = A \cup \{1010\ldots1\}$. Let $A'$ be any list s.t. all numbers from $B$ can be sums of it. From the above argument, $A'$ contains a number from $[\frac{1}{20}; 1]$, from $[5, 100]$, from $[500, 10000]$, etc. As this intervals are non-overlapping, it contains exactly one number from each interval. If it contains any number that is not a right border of some of this intervals, then sum of even all elements of $A'$ is less than $1 + 100 + \ldots + 10^{38}$ - thus $B$ contains number that isn't sum of elements of $A'$. So $A$ contains only right borders of this intervals, so $A' = A$.

Comment: Mihaild thanks for your answer; I would like to upvote but first I need to understand it! For example, why some number $\frac{x}{20}$ must be in A? The numbers in A are rational (and I guess so are the numbers in B, since they are either equal with numbers in A or sums of numbers in A)

Comment: Not $\frac{x}{20}$ must be in $A$, some number from interval $[\frac{x}{20}, x]$ must be in $A$. If all numbers in $A$ are greater than $x$, we can't get $x$ as sum of some numbers of $A$ (even sum of single element would be greater). And if all numbers in $A$ are less than $\frac{x}{20}$, we again can't get $x$ as sum, because sum of even all $20$ elements will be less than $\frac{x}{20}$.

Comment: So, what is the answer here? How many elements must list B have? 21?

Comment: Yes, 21. 21 Is enough (see my example), and 20 isn't: if we have elements $b_1, \ldots, b_{20}$, $b_1 < b_2$ wlog (if all elements are equal, then there are clearly more then one possible list $A$), then there are possibilities $A = \{b_1, \ldots, b_{20}\}$ and $A = \{b_1, b_2 - b_1, b_3, \ldots, b_{20}\}$.